# How to fix "ClassNotFoundException"?

Tags: java, object, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to read and write objects of class Doctor into a file. I keeping getting this "ClassNotFoundException" which prevents me from compiling the code.

I tried using the same method on other files which seems to work just fine.

I get a compilation error at the line  **Vector existing_v = (Vector)aois.readObject();**

```
    package com.example.docapp;

    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class Admin implements Serializable {

       public void addDoctor(Doctor D) throws Exception {
          String url = "com\\example\\docapp\\doctorslist.txt";
          File f = new File(url);

          FileOutputStream afos = new FileOutputStream(f);
          ObjectOutputStream aoos = new ObjectOutputStream(afos);

          if(!f.exists()) { // If file doesnt exist creating and insert a new vector
             Vector<Doctor> v = new Vector<Doctor>();
             v.add(D);
             aoos.writeObject(v);
          }
          else { // Extract the existing vector and add the object to it
             FileInputStream afis = new FileInputStream(f);
             ObjectInputStream aois = new ObjectInputStream(afis);
             Vector<Doctor> existing_v = (Vector<Doctor>)aois.readObject();

             existing_v.add(D);
             aoos.writeObject(existing_v);
             aois.close();
             afis.close();
          }

          System.out.println("\n\nSuccessfully added " + D.name);

          aoos.close();
          afos.close();
       }
    }
```

Comment: try with clean and build

Comment: Do you get `ClassNotFoundException` or compilation error?

Comment: @talex I got an error saying 

error: unreported exception ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: Compiles just fine for me if I add a dummy Doctor class. Which makes sense because the code declares **throws Exception** so will never complain about an exception needing to be caught. Wherever the error is coming from, it's not this code.

Answer (score 0):

The Admin class does not actually need to be serializable. You need to make the `Doctor` class implement `Serializable`.

Also, when you initialize `FileOutputStream`, it will create the file if non-existent. After that, `!f.exists()` will never evaluate to true and it will mess up your attempt to read the object.

```
public void addDoctor(Doctor D) throws Exception {
    String url = "com\\example\\docapp\\doctorslist.txt";
    File f = new File(url);

    FileOutputStream afos;
    ObjectOutputStream aoos;

    if (!f.exists()) { // If file doesnt exist creating and insert a new vector
        afos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        aoos = new ObjectOutputStream(afos);
        Vector<Doctor> v = new Vector<Doctor>();
        v.add(D);
        aoos.writeObject(v);
    } else { // Extract the existing vector and add the object to it
        FileInputStream afis = new FileInputStream(f);
        ObjectInputStream aois = new ObjectInputStream(afis);
        Vector<Doctor> existing_v = (Vector<Doctor>) aois.readObject();

        existing_v.add(D);

        afos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        aoos = new ObjectOutputStream(afos);
        aoos.writeObject(existing_v);
        aois.close();
        afis.close();
    }

    System.out.println("\n\nSuccessfully added " + D.name);

    aoos.close();
    afos.close();
}
```